# Installing NVM on a Docker Alpine image: How to " Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now"

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, nvm

I'm using this Dockerfile:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS coo-php

WORKDIR /srv/app

# Install Node, NVM and Yarn
RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++ bash; \
    echo 'source $HOME/.profile;' >> $HOME/.zshrc; \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash; \
    echo 'export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release;' >> $HOME/.profile; \
    echo 'nvm_get_arch() { nvm_echo "x64-musl"; }' >> $HOME/.profile; \
    NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"; source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh; source $HOME/.profile; \
    nvm -v \
    nvm install 18
```

It runs correctly but the `install.sh` tells me to:

```
#0 3.304 => Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:
#0 3.304 
#0 3.304 export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
#0 3.304 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
#0 3.304 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
#0 3.338 
#0 3.338 Node Version Manager (v0.35.1)
```

How to `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`?

Comment: Try following the steps from here - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script

Answer (score 1):

Add to the next line (after the RUN apk add), `ENV NVM_DIR "$HOME/.nvm"`, also bash is needed in order to source files

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS coo-php
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
WORKDIR /srv/app

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm # or ~/.nvm 

ENV NODE_VERSION 18

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash; \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you, please, add the the correct code to your answer?